# Android - Concurrency problems on multiple activity restarts

Tags: java, android, concurrency, activity-lifecycle

When doing an orientation change in the emulator (ADT v17.0.0), or on a device (original Droid), I noticed that the activity will go through more than one create-destroy cycle sometimes. I found this [blog post](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/android-emulator-bug-while-changing-orientation/) that mentions the problem, but offers no solution.

My app (API 8) currently does a 'last-chance' save of user data in onPause, and retrieves that data in onCreate/onStart, which works fine for a single restart, but gets into concurrency issues if the cycles come back-to-back. Specifically if a load starts before a save is complete, the 'last-chance' data is lost.

I did read the Faster Screen Orientation Change Android-developer article which mentions transferring an Object via onRetainNonConfigurationInstance/getLastNonConfigurationInstance. I tried using onRetain/getLast... like a flag to tell if the activity is "restarting", which works, but I still have the main issue of not knowing if/when any existing save/load operations are completed.

Concurrency & thread-management are not my strongest suits, so I'm looking for a solution that does *at least one* save & load across any number of back-to-back restarts, without memory leaks. Since fast create-destroy cycles could happen for non-orientation reasons, ideas that just involve breaking/handling orientation changes alone aren't really what I'm after.

[Here's a log file](http://studiodisa.com/private/SO-log-multiple-activity-restarts.txt) excerpt with some cycles, you can see where the activity gets created-destroyed twice when going from landscape to portrait. Here's an excerpt of what I've got now:

```
onPause() {
    file_manager.saveTemporaryPattern(); // writes to OutputStream on UI thread
}

onStart() {
    findViewById (R.id.main_screen).post (new Runnable() {
        file_manager.loadTemporaryPattern(); // reads from InputStream on UI thread
    });

    if (getLastNonConfigurationInstance() != null) {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE?
    }
}

onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    return dummy_object;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve the concurrency issue by sending the Load/Save calls to a Handler thread linked to the Application context, rather than the Activity context. Had to setup a Load vs Save token in the calls to check for a Save->Load->Save pattern, avoiding the odd behavior of getting an incomplete activity lifecycle on a landscape->portrait orientation change.

It works in development & on test devices, and doesn't leak the activity context, so we'll see how it does in the wild.

**In YourApp extends Application:**

```
private Handler fileAccessThread = null;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (fileAccessThread == null) {
        fileAccessThread = new Handler();
        token = 0;
    }
}

public void postCallbackFileAccess (int _token, Runnable _callback) {
    switch (_token) {
    case TOKEN_SAVE:
        // Save must follow load, not another save
        if (token == TOKEN_SAVE) { return; }
        token = _token;
        break;

    case TOKEN_LOAD:
//      Have to allow load->load, otherwise data gets lost/deleted
//      if (token == TOKEN_LOAD) { return; }
        token = _token;
        break;
    }

    fileAccessThread.post (_callback);
}
```

**In YourActivity:**

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    ((YourApp) getApplication()).postCallbackFileAccess (
        YourApp.TOKEN_LOAD, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                file_manager.load();
            }
    });
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    ((YourApp) getApplication()).postCallbackFileAccess (
        YourApp.TOKEN_SAVE, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                file_manager.save();
            }
    });
}
```